# Check if file exist then continue with the code in Powershell

Tags: file, powershell, loops, exists

I need to check if some pdf exists in c:\pdf and if exists continue with the execution, if not, check again every 15th second.

My actual code just checks for files in the folder and print if there is something, if not just repeat again and again. My problem is that sometimes my code deletes the items before printing, thats why I want to loop in the file check and only continue with my code, if a file exists.

My code:

```
Do {
    $fileDirectory = "C:\pdf";
    foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $fileDirectory)
    {
        $filePath = $fileDirectory + "\" + $file;
        Start-Process –FilePath $filePath –Verb Print -WindowStyle Minimized -PassThru
    }
    Start-Sleep -s 2
    Remove-Item c:\pdf\* -recurse
    Get-Process AcroRd32 | % { $_.CloseMainWindow() }
    sleep 15
} while ($true)
```

Comment: You shouldn't process all files before deleting them, more files can be added in the interim, you should process and delete them one at a time to help reduce the chances of this race condition causing you to lose unprocessed files.

Comment: I removed the tag `pdf` because your question is not *about* PDF files. You can ask the same thing about any other file extension.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use simple while block:

```
While (!(Test-Path C:\pdf\file.pdf -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
{
  # endless loop, when the file will be there, it will continue
}

# Next code block here #
```

Comment: Thats works with my code, thank you very much. I just try with my code and the code print just one pdf, if i put more than one the script ignore the other ones. My code right now:                                                                                                                       Do {
 
 While (!(Test-Path C:\pdf\*.pdf -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
{
  # endless loop, when the file will be there, it will continue
}

#my code

}

while ($true)